# KeyEvent issue on JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, jtextpane, keyevent

I am new to GUI programming.  While practicing `KeyEvent` handling on Java Swing `JTextarea` I face one problem.  The listener interface is implemented by text area itself.

When I pressed `VK_ENTER` key in text area I get text from text area then I displayed that text into `JTextPane`. After that I set text as empty string on text area.  Here I used `keyPressed` key event - it is creating  one new line in text area but already I set text area row as 0 (zero).

Actually I want one row in text area I don't want two line in text area, How to resolve this problem?

This is my code:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {

   try {
       if (evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
           if (evt.isShiftDown()) {  
              textArea .setText(textArea.getText() + "\n");
           } else {   
                inputMsg = textArea.getText().trim();
                textArea.setText(EMPTYSTRING);
                if (!inputMsg.equals(EMPTYSTRING)) {   
                   textPane.setText(inputMsg);
                }
                textArea.requestFocus();
              }
          }
     } catch (Exception ex) {
         logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception in textArea.keyReleased() : ", ex);
     }
}
```

Comment: For better answers sooner post a snippet of code you have written.

Comment: show some code that you've tried?

Comment: Since you are new to Swing, don't consider Low Level KeyListeners instead have a look at [KeyBinding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), which is meant for Swing. To resolve the line thingy, simply use [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) which implements everything in a single line.

Comment: while i press VK_ENTER + VK_SHIFT i want to create new line so i have to use textarea regards textfield

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Actually I want one row in textarea I don't want two line in textarea, How to resolve this problem?

then why are you using textarea?, use `JTextField`

**EDIT** after asker's comments:

The additional new line is coming as you are providing your logic in `keyPressed` method. When you release the key, the ENTER makes it effect on the text area (by adding new line for ENTER).

You can try your logic in `public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)` method instead and it **should** work.

Other way could be to consume the released event in pressed event after your logic, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: while i press VK_ENTER + VK_SHIFT i want to create new line so i have to use textarea regards textfield.

Comment: ok, but it is still not clear why and when you want to avoid 2 lines in text area? can you update your question with a small sample working code with that issue for better help?

Comment: Suppose I use KeyReleased instead of Keypressed for capturing keyEvent on JTextArea ,While I press VK_ENTER key my code get text from JTextArea and paste those text in JTextPane and cursor position retain in same line(return empty String).Suppose use KeyPressed do the same thing it create one more line during first time pressed. VK_ENTER.

Answer (score 2):

When you have input of one single line of any length, you should consider using `JTextField`.

Ideally, `JTextArea` can be used for accepting multiline input.

Comment: while i press VK_ENTER + VK_SHIFT i want to create new line so i have to use textarea regards textfield.