# SHIFT + ENTER, & ENTER in the same component in Java

Tags: java, swing, key, behavior, key-bindings

In my program hte <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> key does a new line in a text area, but when y remove the established behavior of the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key the program crashes, can i do that?, add functionality for <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> keys and remove the standard behavior of the Enter key.
My following code is, for the  remove behavior of Enter key:

```
public void removeEnterBehavior(){
    KeyStroke enter = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER");
    InputMap inputMap = messageTextArea.getInputMap();
    inputMap.put(enter, "none");
}
```

For the new line with the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> keys, my code is:

```
@Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {   
         if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER && (e.getModifiers() & InputEvent.SHIFT_MASK) != 0){
             addNewLine();
         }
    }
```

Also the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key have to call a method in the keyPressed method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is similar to [keyEventIssue with keyPressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14055039/keyevent-issue-on-jtextarea/14055233#14055233)

You should use `keyReleased` rather than `keyPressed` to avoid the enter behaviour.

Please check my answer in the above link and let me know if it doesn't help or if your issue is different

Comment: You fix it, the problem is that I did not put the method inside the event :/, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 3):

Why are you mixing `KeyBinding` and `KeyListener`?

Dont use `KeyListener`/`KeyAdapter` with Swing. Always use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

You should do something like this to listen for <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> **(it can be in key release or key pressed)**:

```
jta.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK, true), "Shift+Enter released");
jta.getActionMap().put("Shift+Enter released", new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        System.out.println("Shift+Enter released");
    }
});
```

The important part being:

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK, true)
```

Notice the last 2 parameters. The `true` is used so `Keybinding` is added for *on release* of the key, though you can use `false` for when key is pressed and the same results will occur. The other parameter is for when <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> is down.

Also to remove <kbd>ENTER</kbd> you should do it on the **key pressed**:

```
KeyStroke enter = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0, false);
InputMap inputMap = jta.getInputMap();
inputMap.put(enter, "none");
```

Notice I use `false` which means the keybinding is placed when key is *pressed*.

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                JTextArea jta = new JTextArea(20, 20);

                //remove enter pressed
                KeyStroke enter = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0, false);
                InputMap inputMap = jta.getInputMap();
                inputMap.put(enter, "none");

                //add shift+enter keybinding can be on pressed or released i.e false or true
                jta.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, KeyEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK, true), "Shift+Enter released");
                jta.getActionMap().put("Shift+Enter released", new AbstractAction() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                        System.out.println("Shift+Enter released");
                    }
                });

                frame.add(jta);

                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that i used to remove the deafult JTable´s row navigation that works on enter and shift-enter

```
    ActionMap am = table.getActionMap();        
    table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER,0), "Enter pressed");
    table.getInputMap(JTable.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, InputEvent.SHIFT_DOWN_MASK, false), "Shift+Enter pressed");
    am.put("Enter pressed",null);
    am.put("Shift+Enter pressed", null);
```

That null can be replaced by any custom action (e.g. AbstractAction) you need. In my case i used a method from a custom interface parameter on the constructor of my custom JTable.